# Alinear texto al centro con FPDF

Tags: php, php7, fpdf

Quisiera saber como puedo hacer para alinear el texto al centro usando la función `Text()` de la librería **FPDF**.

```
$this->Text(10.5,1.5,'TEXTO A COLOCAR');
```

Utilizo esa función para poner texto en el encabezado del documento pero quisiera saber si hay alguna forma de hacer que el texto aparezca en el centro para asi no tener que estar dandole al tanteo un valor a la coordenada `x` y también para no tener que usar la función `Cell()`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4742794/how-to-center-text-in-fpdf

Comment: Ya que no deseas usar Cell() -y asumo que tampoco MultiCell ni Write() - una forma complicada de hacerlo sería: 
1) obtener el ancho de tu página con GetPageWidth()  
2) Obtener el ancho que ocupará tu texto con GetStringWidth()  
3) Calcular la posición x en la página para colocar el texto como (GetPageWidth() - GetStringWidth() ) / 2, luego mover el puntero hacia x con SetX(x) y por último, colocar tu texto

Comment: @JuanCarlos gracias por tu respuesta, funciona perfecto

Comment: @JuanCarlos ya que el OP ha indicado que tu respuesta le ha ayudado, seria conveniente que lo agregues como respuesta y este la marca como respondida... con tal de que tu y el puedan recibir la recompensa de reputacion, posibles medallas. y quede como una respuesta en el sitio, recuerda siempre dar una respuesta completa con una explicacion y apuntando a la documentacion que mensiona la solucion, si se trato de un sitio externo.

Answer (score 0):

Ya que no deseas usar Cell() -y asumo que tampoco MultiCell ni Write() - una forma complicada de hacerlo sería:

1. Obtener el ancho de tu página con `GetPageWidth()`
2. Obtener el ancho que ocupará tu texto con `GetStringWidth()`
3. Calcular la posición x en la página para colocar el texto como `x = (GetPageWidth() - GetStringWidth() ) / 2`
4. Mover el puntero hacia x con `SetX(x)` y por último, colocar tu texto